# Ordenar divs en una lista

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo una lista de divs, la cual tiene un nombre y un precio.
Hice una función para ordenar los divs ASC y DESC, almaceno en un objeto el div(objeto) y el precio que se muestra.

Después hago el orden con una función básica de JS. El problema es que cuando trato de ponerlo ya ordenado en la lista me aparece otra cosa.

Así se ve al inicio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que se ejecuta cuando doy sortear, ahorita para pruebas solo sirve ASC.

```
$(document).on('click','.sort',function(){
      sortBy('asc');
    });

    function sortBy(m)
    {
      var result;
      switch (m)
      {
        case 'desc':
          var arr = [];
          $('.propDetails').each(function(){
            var superObj = {};
            var obj = this;
            var value = parseInt($(this).attr('price'));
            superObj.obj = obj;
            superObj.value = value;
            arr.push(superObj);
          });

          arr.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.value < b.value) {
              return 1;
            }
            if (a.value > b.value) {
              return -1;
            }
            return 0;
          });

          result = arr;
        break;

        case 'asc':
          var arr = [];
          $('.propDetails').each(function(){
            var superObj = {};
            var obj = this;
            var value = parseInt($(this).attr('price'));
            superObj.obj = obj;
            superObj.value = value;
            arr.push(superObj);
          });

          arr.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.value > b.value) {
              return 1;
            }
            if (a.value < b.value) {
              return -1;
            }
            return 0;
          });

          result = arr;
        break;


        default:
        break;
      }

      reBuildList(arr);
    }
```

Después armo de nuevo la lista, ahorita no tiene muchas validaciones si el índice existe o no, ya lo pondré más adelante, pero me inquieta que no se pueda mostrar el resultado. Este es el código.

```
function reBuildList(a)
{
  console.log(a);
  var h = "",i=0,ii=1;
  for (i; i < a.length;)
  {
    var obj1 = a[i].obj;
    var obj2 = a[ii].obj;
    h+='<div class="row">' +
      '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">' +
        obj1 +
      '</div>' +

      '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">' +
        obj2 +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>';

    i = i + 2;
    ii = ii + 2;
  }
  $('#mapList').html(h);
}
```

El resultado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es la impresión de la consola y el arreglo que se formó

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que estoy omitiendo, bienvenidas propuestas.

Comment: Pero al final como quieres ordenar los div? de mayor a menor?

Comment: Para efectos de prueba, ahorita es de menor a mayor, ya despues implementaré las otras formas de orden, lo que me interesa es saber como vuelvo a pintar los DIV´s que ya fueron acomodados

Comment: Seria bueno ver como contruyes tus divs, puedes compartir el html?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví si lo necesitan.

Al momento de volver a pintar, estaba pintando los objetos como tal.
Tuve que meterme dentro del objeto y buscar los nodos que contuvieran el HTML en string, Aquí los encontré.

```
function reBuildList(a)
    {
      var h = "",i=0,ii=1;
      h+=lastHeader;
      for (i; i < a.length;)
      {
        var obj1 = a[i].obj.parentNode.innerHTML;
        var obj2 = a[ii].obj.parentNode.innerHTML;
        h+='<div class="row">' +
          '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">' +
            obj1 +
          '</div>' +

          '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">' +
            obj2 +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>';

        i = i + 2;
        ii = ii + 2;
      }
      $('#mapList').html('');
      $('#mapList').append(h);
    }
```

Quizá no sea la mejor forma, de todas maneras agradezco una forma más limpia de hacer este proceso.